# Problema ao usar SetLocale em C

Tags: c, acentuação

Galera, bom dia.
Estou iniciando na programação C (venho do Python e do JavaScript).

Tenho um problema para usar a função setLocale, que define o tipo de linguagem utilizada, permitindo o uso de acentuação e etc. Quando coloco a função no meu programa e digito qualquer valor com o uso do ponto (exemplo: 0.4) o programa termina instataneamente. Sei que o erro é no setLocale, porque quando tiro a função o programa roda como o esperado.

Abaixo está meu código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: O objetivo do uso do SetLocale (que é usar acentuação e tals) funciona corretamente, só não entendo o erro.

Comment: Inclua o código sempre como texto e formate-o com `Ctrl-k` ou utilizando o botão `{}` do editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, acredito que o seu problema seja que o setlocale() esteja passando a base numérica brasileira onde usamos "," no lugar de "." que é o padrão. Tente rodar seu código utilizando vírgulas, deve funcionar.

Comment: Era isso msm, vlw.

Answer (score 0):

A chamada de `setlocale( LC_ALL, "" );` (com o segundo parametro em branco), faz com que o locale padrão do programa seja setado automaticamente conforme as variáveis de ambiente do seu sistema:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale( LC_ALL, "" );
    printf( "ÁÉÍÓÚ\n" );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    printf("Olá Mundo");
    return 0;
}
```

A primeira letra deve ser maiúscula, o Lacobus te deu uma dica para ser setado automaticamente o setlocale do seu programa, mas se você quiser fazer manualmente, escreva Portuguese com a primeira letra maiúscula.

Answer (score 0):

Prove:
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese-brazilian");